# How to get the number of friends of users who liked a Facebook post with graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the number of friends of users who liked a Facebook post, with the below URL.

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=115045892222991_372512119809699&fields=likes.summary(true).limit(20000000){friends,name,picture}

I am getting users's name and picture with the above call, but not friends count.
I know we can only get the details of users who installed the app, but I just need the total count.

Can anybody tell me how to get the count?

I am using version 2.8 of graph APIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know we can only get the details of users who installed the app, but I just need the total count.
>
> Can anybody tell me how to get the count?

That is not possible; your app would still first of all need `user_friends` permission from the user who’s total friend count you want to read.

Comment: I have that permission

Comment: From the user that liked the post?

Comment: Not from them, so may be that's the reason. Sorry